# Correct syntax for require required

Tags: solidity, calldata, require

I am getting following error message with require statement:

> Error: Wrong argument count for function call: 0 arguments given but
>   expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use "" as
>   argument to provide empty calldata.
>
> ```
>         require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());
>                 ^--------------------------------------------^ :
> ```
>
> Error: No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup.
>
> ```
>         require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());
>         ^-----^
> ```

The require statement is:

```
require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in the `require` statement, but in the `addr1.call.value(addr2)()` function call inside it.

In [solc 0.4.x](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.0/types.html#members-of-addresses), this function would take no input arguments and return one output value of type `bool`, so your code would actually compile successfully.

In [solc 0.5.x](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/types.html#members-of-addresses), this function takes one input argument of type `bytes` and returns one output value of type `bool` and one output value of type `bytes`.

In short, just change this:

```
require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());
```

To this:

```
(bool success,) = msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)("");
require(success);
```

Or to this if you want to do something with the second output value:

```
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)("");
require(success);
... // do something with `returnData`
```

Answer (score 1):

The require function should be used to ensure valid conditions that cannot be detected until execution time as specified in the solidity read the docs.

In your case:

```
require(msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)());
```

It returns two values one is of type **bool** and the other of type **bytes**, whereas **require** expects a Boolean (single parameter) value for execution. Thus, you are getting the above error.

Correct syntax for require:

```
require("Anything that returns a boolean (Be it an expression/a function call/external call etc)")

Example:
require(msg.value % 2 == 0, "Even value required.");
```

Comment: @balajipachi, sorry your explanation is not clear. On the other hand the answer above your's clearly bifurcates require into two parts. Sorry I can't understand what you mean by "It" in your sentence " It returns two values one is of type bool .....".

Comment: You can find more details about require here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/units-and-global-variables.html#error-handling